# Some responsive css issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made this wordpress theme but I need help for some css issues.

> 1- Center on mobile

http://www.hekim.deniz-tasarim.site/

Normally, I know that we must give spesific code here to get help.However now,I cant give spesific code because I dont know how to fix it.I tried some methods but I couldnt make it what I want

There is an OUR DEPARTMENT section on homepage, you can find it via search the OUR DEPARTMENT .

There are pictures for that section.

In mobile screens ( Iphone5 - 320x568 px / Iphone 6 - 377x667 ) , the pictures are not centered.I want to center them for mobile screens.

> 2- Broken align for tablets

There is WHY CHOOSE US on homepage.In that section, there are some elements which made by bootstrap 3 as col-md-4 . In Ipad screen ( 1024x768 px ) , Medical counselling. element shown alone in one line while I wait it seems on one line with Outdoor Checkup. and Rehabilitation.

What cause the broken align?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer to your first question is:

Find the upper element that has group of `col` classes of your problematic `img` element and add `text-align: center;` to the element that has `col` classes.

**Reason**: Your `col` classes act like a block element. Those block elements can be aligned using `text-align`.

### Answer to your second question is:

"Why Choose Us?" elements have `.icon-box` class. You can give them minimum height. Use `min-height: 300px;` worked for me. You can increase the value as you need of course.

**Reason**: Float option is problematic for those elements because the blocks don't have a proper height and the blocks obviously float to each other. You can attach an equal height to them to fix the floating action.